# Splitting workbook and changing named ranges to not reference the original workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to split my workbook, however when I do so the named ranges in the new workbooks refer to the original workbook. I do not want this, as I have copied the source for these references into the new workbooks as well. Thus I want to delete the reference to the old workbook in the named range. I have tried to change this by replacing the reference to nothing, however it does not work. What am I doing wrong or is there any other way? I have also tried to delete the named range and replace them by new named ranges, but the refers to part of the named range is a function with =offset(...). This does not seem to work either in VBA.

```
Sub RenameNamedRanges()
    Dim all_names, n
    all_names = Array("1stNamedRange", "2ndNamedRange", "3rdNamedRange")
    For Each n In all_names
        Names(n).Replace (RefersTo, "[Original_workbook.xlsm]", "")
    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to delete the named range, and then create a new one.

```
Names(n).Delete

ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add _ 
    Name:="newNamedRange", _ 
    RefersTo:="=Sheet1!$A$1:$D$3"
```

Can check the output of what the existing range refers to and assign to a variable to use when adding the new range.

```
 Debug.Print(Names(n).RefersTo)
```

Can also use the Replace function to replace part of the string you want to replace

```
Replace(Names(n).RefersTo, "[Original_workbook.xlsm]", "")
```